# Парсинг JSON Qt 4.8

Tags: json, qt, парсер, qt4

Помогите распарсить вот такой json:

```
{
 "meta": { "v":"1.2"
          ,"p":"259355195"
          ,"a":103
          ,"t":"aaaaaaa"
          ,"d":1443729008   }
,"data": [ {"i":78585,"f":103,"t":"сообщение1","d":299977900}
          ,{"i":78584,"f":259,"t":"сообщение2","d":299975624}
          ,{...}
          , ...
          ,{...}    ]
}
```

Т.е. в массиве data находится большое число объектов. Использую Qt 4.8.6 и библиотеку QJson. Непонятно как пройтись по массиву объектов и распарсить каждый из них. Еще проблема возникает в том, что, если размер json-файла больше 100 кБ парсер не работает (файл, который мне нужно парсить занимает порядка 300 кБ). Что можно сделать с этим?

**Обновление**

`errorString()` возвращает пустую строку, но при этом если я попытаюсь вывести в `qDebug()`

```
QVariantMap result = jsonParser.parse(sJson.toLocal8Bit(), &ok).toMap(); qDebug() << result["t"].toString();
```

То получаю также пустую строку.

Comment: Что возвращает `errorString()` у объекта парсера, когда, собственно, парсинг завершается с ошибкой?

Comment: Если соотносительно Вашему примеру данных из вопроса, то чтобы получить `t`, необходимо выполнить: `jsonParser.parse(sJson.toLocal8Bit(), &ok).toMap().value("meta").toMap().value("t").toString();`

Comment: И, по идее, кодировку utf-8 лучше использовать, т.е. `sJson.toUtf8()`.

Comment: @alexis031182 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если производить выборку значения соотносительно примеру данных из вопроса, то, например, чтобы получить элемент `t`, необходимо изменить строку запроса следующим образом:

```
QString val
    = jsonParser.parse(sJson.toUtf8(),&ok)
        .toMap().value("meta").toMap().value("t").toString();
```

или

```
QString val
    = jsonParser.parse(sJson.toUtf8(),&ok)
        .toMap()["meta"].toMap()["t"].toString();
```

Оба варианта равнозначны и их безопасно можно использовать даже в том случае, если на любом из шагов окажется, что запрашиваемой ветки "дерева" не существует. В этом случае результатом выполнения команды окажется пустая строка.

Отличие метода `value()` от оператора `operator[]` у `QMap` заключается в том, что для `value()` в качестве второго аргумента можно указать значение, которое будет возвращено, если искомого элемента не окажется в наличии.

Разумеется, если требование к скорости работы рассматриваемого кода принципиально, то имеет смысл проверять существование данных на каждом шаге (например, посредством метода `contains()` у `QMap`), т.к. при отсутствии значения будет каждый раз вызываться конструктор по умолчанию для каждого запрашиваемого элемента.

Перебор данных по ключу `data` может быть осуществлён при помощи следующей конструкции:

```
const QVariantList items
    = jsonParser.parse(sJson.toUtf8(),&ok)
        .toMap()["data"].toList();

foreach(const QVariant &item, items) {
    // Доступ, например, к элементу "f".
    QString f_val = item.toMap()["f"];
}
```

Для json-данных следует использовать кодировку utf-8, если нет иного соглашения с приёмной/отправляющей данные стороной.